# Parallax effect jumping

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a parallax effect on my site but on scrolling it seems rather jumpy as follows:

[image]

Here is the code:

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        jQuery('*[class^="prlx"]').each(function(r) {
          var pos = $(this).offset().top;
          var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
          jQuery('*[class^="prlx"]').css('top', +(scrolled * 0.6) + 'px');
        });
      });
    });
```

```css
*[class^="prlx"] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: 110%;
}
.prlx-2 {
  background-image: url('http://www.roscodigitalmedia.co.uk/rosco/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/bigstock-Artist-Photographer-Retouches-91840682.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid homeHeader">
  <div class="prlx-2">

  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: On further testing, it seems to be working perfectly in Chrome however Safari & FireFox is showing the issue.

Comment: Why do you use this `*[class^="prlx"]` selector?

Comment: So it can be used on multiple elements without replicating the code

Comment: No difference with that i'm afraid

Comment: It's true. Let me check.

Comment: There will be a (performance) difference, if there are an unrealistic number of elements that satisfy your selector on the page. You might want to look into [pure CSS parallax effects](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/), which doesn't require recomputing offsets whenever a scroll event is triggered. Alternatively, you might want to explore [throttling/debouncing options](jqyer throttle debounce) for your scroll. p/s: Also, it helps to have a **functional** example—the code snippet you have posted does not work, or come close to resembling the image you have posted.

Comment: Change `scrolled * 0.6` to `scrolled * 0.3`. I checked it locally and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see anything "wrong" on your code. I will bet that the cause are the 2,1MB of your image, being resized from 2500px to the window width. Take into account that the browser is trying to "paint" the image and calculate position on every scroll value...

I'd approach it with background position on css but keeping with yours, the problem seems to be focused on performance. What you do on JS is a bit inefficient, cause first you select all `'*[class^="prlx"]'` loop through them, and then you apply again to all of them in every loop a position recalculation by looking again for them. As you are looping through elements, you can use `this` element and apply the change on it. Save $this to a variable is just to not apply jQuery twice on the same element and save a little resources, but in this case may not be so important.

Here on my laptop I don't see it jumpy. Try that and using a smaller image to see if it improves a bit the performance.

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        jQuery('*[class^="prlx"]').each(function(r) {
          var $this = $(this);
          var pos = $this.offset().top;
          var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
          $this.css('top', +(scrolled * 0.6) + 'px');
        });
      });
    });
```

```css
*[class^="prlx"] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: 110%;
}
.prlx-2 {
  background-image: url('http://www.roscodigitalmedia.co.uk/rosco/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/bigstock-Artist-Photographer-Retouches-91840682.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid homeHeader">
  <div class="prlx-2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I have reduced the file size to 337KB and tested it and its still a little jerky, buttery smooth in Chrome but Safari and FireFox still jumpy, any ideas?

Comment: It's true that firefox does it harsh... Have you tried to do the test with an image of the exact width? I'm trying and it flows better.

Comment: Hm, for me now Opera seems to be handling specific parallax image scrolls perfectly, all other browsers (Chrome, Firexox, Edge) are jumpy and not smooth at all (on  desktop). Opera is the parallax champ' for me today.. Maybe useful to know this for testing.

Answer (score 2):

I'd add `will-change` to your CSS attributes. This helps the browser to figure out how to handle elements. It will prepare the browser for an animation, so it won't be "surprised" that it needs to change how an element looks like.

```
*[class^="prlx"] {
    ...
    will-change: top;
}
```

Secondly, you should experiment with various other techniques besides using `top` attribute. Try `background-position`, `margin-top`, or `transform: translate(0, Xpx)`. I'd hope for the latter one the most.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not the code that's the problem, but the scrolling. Most mice have little notches in their scroll wheel.

[image]

This makes for uneven scrolling on almost all webpages. Arrow keys have the same effect. Page up and Page down are really jumpy. You could try finding a mouse that has smooth scrolling, but other than that, I don't think that there is a solution.